# Setting a true/false value when an date-picker has been edited

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having some trouble with a form that I have built. My form contains bootstrap date-picker fields. They are populated with dates from my database (if any have been entered).
I would like to display a message, so that if the user has entered a new date and tries to exit the form without saving, a warning will pop up informing the user that there are unsaved changes.

```
<template>
    <b-modal v-model="open">
        <b-form-row class="middle-align" >
          <b-col lg="6">
            <b-form-group :label="'Date of vacation start'">
              <b-form-datepicker v-model="user.vacationStartDate"/>
            </b-form-group>
          </b-col>
        </b-form-row>
      <b-button @click="submit()">Save</b-button>
      <b-button @click="checkIfSaved()">Close</b-button>
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

I have made a boolean called isSaved, which is set to true when the data is first loaded. Then I have added a function called checkIfSaved, which will throw a warning if isSaved changes to false.

```
  checkIfSaved(){
    if(!this.isSaved){
      this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('You have unsaved changes. Do you wish to continue?', {
        title: 'Warning!',
        okTitle: 'yes',
        cancelTitle: 'no',
        footerClass: 'p-2',
        hideHeaderClose: false,
        centered: true
      }).then(value => {
        if(value) {
          this.open = false
        }
      })
    }
  },
```

My problem is that I cannot get the program to detect if the user has entered a new date or not.
After looking at some previous posts here, I thought it was just a matter of creating a watcher, but it has not worked for me.

```
watch: {
  user: {
    deep: true,
    handler(val) {
      val.isSaved = false
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: `val.isSaved = false` should be `this.isSaved = false`.  `val` is just the new value of user after it's been changed